# Problems with multiple Tkinter buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I was working on I just couldn't get to work, I've written an example that I think displays the issue:

```
from tkinter import *

listing = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def PressedButton(listing):
    print(listing)

global root
root = Tk()
ListButton = []
for i in range(0, len(listing)):
    ListButton.append(Button(root, text= listing[i], command = lambda: 
PressedButton(listing[i])))
    ListButton[i].grid(row = i)
```

When I run this I always have the number 4 printed no matter what button I select, but all the buttons do have their correct respective number on them.

Thanks a lot for any help you guys could provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are many things related to bad programming practices within your code, and surely you have to read more about [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture) expressions, so for the moment all what I can do is to provide you a solution to make your code work.

Change this:

```
... command = lambda: PressedButton(listing[i]) ...
```

to

```
... command = lambda i=i: PressedButton(listing[i]) ...
```